# Inaccurate last modified times with both PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, timestamp

Both of these are displaying the wrong time. The modified time is 5:30 AM. PHP displays 12:30 PM and Javascript 10:30 (AM or PM?). It seems PHP is the way to go, but no scripts I've found are correct on my system. I'm using XAMPP and Windows XP. How would one go about displaying an accurate last modified time?

```
<?
$last_modified = filemtime("header.php");
    echo("last modified ");
    echo(date("m.j.y h:ia", $last_modified));
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(document.lastModified);
    </script>
```

Comment: This seems to be a statement rather than a question.

Comment: Is the file-system's mtime using a different timezone to PHP?

Comment: any idea where the php timezone is located in xampp?

Comment: http://wpcanada.ca/2010/setting-the-correct-timezone-in-xampp/

Comment: You can also set it during code execution: [date_default_timezone_set](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting default time zone like UTC in below code it may help u

```
<?
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); 
$last_modified = filemtime("header.php");
    echo("last modified ");
    echo(date("m.j.y h:ia", $last_modified));
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(document.lastModified);
    </script>
```

Comment: i actually used the comment by aurimusL, but this also works.